# Finding an issue in ending the python process

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webautomation

I have a script to run a webdriver in a headless mode. I'm observing that after the whole execution of the script, the process is still running.

Here's the imitation of the issue I'm facing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webbrowser import Chrome
from ssl import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class PythonOrg():

    def Setup(self):
        self.chrome_options = Options()
        self.chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())) #not a headless
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options)

    
    def GetLink(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://www.python.org')
        print(driver.title)
        driver.close()
        print('Closed the driver')


inst = PythonOrg()


inst.Setup()
inst.GetLink()
```

Note: This is just a replication of the issue from the actual project.

Help me understand how can I manage the process when it gets completed, I'm new to Python platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two options for webdriver - quit() and close()

```
# Closes the current window
driver.close()

# All windows related to driver instance will quit
driver.quit()
```

Seems you are just closing the window, thus why the instance is still active.
Use `quit()` to terminate the instance.

Comment: Help me understand here. If the Chrome instance has only one tab/window if that's closed doesn't that close the whole Chrome itself. Does the webdriver has some other mechanics to be aware of?

Comment: Webdriver is the process responsible for open/close/etc. operations for the browser.
Even the browser is closed, thus do not means the webdriver should be terminated.
Different cases and usages, that`s why there is such method.